# KeyError 'request' in DRF

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am checking in serializer if product exists in cart or not and I am using this

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    in_cart = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'in_cart']

    def get_in_cart(self, obj):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            added_to_cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=user, product_id=obj.id).exists()
            return added_to_cart
        else:
            return False
```

It works fine but I cannot add product to the cart because of that `request`

my cart model like this

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user} cart item'


class ItemsListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

When I post product id to add cart it throws this error

> user = self.context['request'].user   KeyError: 'request'

I need to make both work but adding item to cart is being problem.
How can I solve this? Thank you beforehand!

Comment: Change `serializer_class = ProductSerializer()` to **`serializer_class = ProductSerializer`** . The `serializer_class` attribute should be a ***class***, not an instnace

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to [pass](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) the request to the context before usage. So the calling of serializer should look like this:

```
ProductSerializer(product, context={'request': request})
```

---

With `ListAPIView` class you don't even need this, because by default it would be available in the serializer due to the default implementation of `get_serializer_context` method:

```
def get_serializer_context(self):
    """
    Extra context provided to the serializer class.
    """
    return {
        'request': self.request,
        'format': self.format_kwarg,
        'view': self
    }
```

Although you could override it if needed. Also, take a note that `serializer_class` accepts a callable object, it should be `serializer_class = ProductSerializer`.

Comment: But where should I include this in the view or somewhere?

Comment: Most likely yes, on the place where you need the context. Also, it would be great to check that `request` is passed, because there may be parts where it does not need.

Comment: I used your given answer before giving it to stackoverflow but it says `unresolved reference` when I add to the view I added my `ItemListView` in the answer please have a look?

Comment: @Nerd I can not reproduce the error with your example. Can you push the reproducible part to the git and provide a link?

Comment: thank you very much it worked your answer did not solved my problem but your answer is very close to the answer. I used this `ProductSerializer(product, context=self.context)`. That's why I am accepting your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem while using nested serializers. As mentioned above, you just can pass `self.context['request']` to the context of nested serializer:

```
'author': GETUserSerializer(
    recipe.author,
    context={'request': self.context['request']}
).data,
```